# Make Firefox log requests and responses by default

Tags: firefox

Almost every time I use the debug console I have to right click and tick "Log request and response bodies". It's so annoying to forget it from time to time and then have to redo whatever I did to trigger it; and it clears every time I close and open the console.

Is there *any* way, such as an `about:config` variable, to make it log these bodies by default? I would even recompile Firefox from sources to do this if someone can tell me where the default is set.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from the [relevant issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602572), this is not something controlled by `about:config` and the value lives while the developer tools are opened.

Comment: That issue was closed in 2011 and marked resolved in Firefox 4.x. Since then the behavior of the option has changed, so this bug is no longer relevant. Meanwhile this relevant issue has recently been opened: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1064458 Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @Luc thank you, your link is much more relevant here. Though, for now the answer is the same - the checkbox is going down to default every time you open up developer tools..